# Can I use StringFormat as TextWriterFormat? kfprintf / kprintf usage

Tags: f#, printf

I've got function to log to console

```
        Printf.kprintf
            (printfn
                "[%s][%A] %s"
                    <| level.ToString()
                    <| DateTime.Now)
                    format // fprint to System.Console.Out maybe
```

but it's using Printf.StringFormat as format and now I want to follow same logic and print it to file.

So I try

```
        Printf.kfprintf 
            (fun f -> 
                fprintfn file "[%s][%A] " 
                        <| level.ToString()
                        <| DateTime.Now
                ) file (format)
```

And there are two things I can't understand. Why there is `unit -> 'A` instead of `string -> 'A` ? How should I use it? And Can I use my `StringFormat` here as `TextWriterFormat` ?

Another trouble with this is that with first snippet I inherit `format` to `string -> 'Result` thing but in kfprintf  I can't do it because there is `unit -> 'Result` and format message appears before `[x][x]` stuff. I guess I can somehow inherit `format` to `f` but I can't find good example, the only I found is part of F# compiler:

```
[<CompiledName("PrintFormatToTextWriter")>]
let fprintf (os: TextWriter) fmt  = kfprintf (fun _ -> ()) os fmt 

[<CompiledName("PrintFormatLineToTextWriter")>]
let fprintfn (os: TextWriter) fmt  = kfprintf (fun _ -> os.WriteLine()) os fmt
```

But how can I use this `unit` ? How can I post message after my message?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think you need to use `Printf.kfprintf`, you can carry on using `Printf.kprintf` as the *inner* `fprintfn` uses the `TextWriter`.

```
let logToWriter writer level format =
    Printf.kprintf (fprintfn writer "[%s][%A] %s" 
                    <| level.ToString() 
                    <| System.DateTime.Now) format
```

Also see [this](https://bitbucket.org/lost/alternate-f/src/8ed7466a0efc/src/absil/ildiag.fs#cl-28) for an example of using `Printf.kfprintf`.

Comment: I used inner fprintfn there but maybe it's wrong because it's kind-of recursive...